# Lattice Diamond 2.1

Tags: vhdl, active-hdl, lattice-diamond

I upgraded my machine from WinXP to Win7, and at the same installed Lattice Diamond 3.1. My more complex simulations hang, Active-HDL uses 100% CPU time and is obviously in an infinite loop. Stupidly I don't have the installation of Lattice Diamond 2.1 or 2.2, and unbelievably Lattice only allows you to download the latest version. No fallbacks!

Does anyone have an installation file for Lattice Diamond 2.1 or at a pinch 2.2? I can provide an FTP to put it on if some has. I know its a big file, probably 1G+.

Actually I was able to just copy the Active-HDL 9.2 directory from Win7 in a virtual box on another machine, and overwrite the Active-HDL 9.4 directory. I still wouldn't mind an old installation file but at least I can simulate now. And Diamond 3.1 its actually possible to eliminate bkm warnings and errors. There were 2 many bugs in 2.1, tech support actually admitted my warnings were Diamond bugs not flaws in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found you can download older version from support -> Software archive

Actual link:
http://www.latticesemi.com/en/Support/SoftwareArchive.aspx